# How to save Image using CharField max_length=1024 i.e longext in django

Tags: django

I am working on a project where we want the profile pic of user to be in a CharField i.e longtext. Now, in ModelForm for updating the user's profile I want to get profile pic and want to resize and compress it and save it in database with unique name like using timestamp.
The problem that I have is that I can get image name using cleaned_data from form but cannot process it for resize or compression and it gives me the error of no file or directory is found

Comment: Do you want to save the encode image (base64) or the path to the image?

Comment: I want to save the image name with path.

Comment: Isnt ImageField an option? You could have a custom name function to rename it, and on save resize it

Comment: I am not allowed to use ImageField for it.
Have to use CharField.

Comment: Can you paste the code for your model, form and view?